# Reading individual digits of an integer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an unsigned int, say 12345 for example.  I want to iterate through each one of the digits of this integer and put them into an array, like so:
    array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
The number of digits in the integer is already known and stored in another variable, size.

Can someone propose a simple algorithm that would iterate over the digits in the integer and extract them individually?

update
Here's what I'm thinking:

```
    function  (const unsigned int value){
        //find length of unsigned int 'value'
        unsigned int i = value;
        unsigned int x = value;
        int j = 0;  //counter
        for(int j = 0; i > 0; j++){
            i = i/10;
        }//end for
        size = j;
        array = new int[size];
        //read in digits of 'value' into array
        for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--){   
            array[i] = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
        }//end for
    }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You just described the algorithm. Read the digit chars one at a time and put them in an array. Stop doing that when a char you read is no longer a digit char.

Comment: WhozCraig--I forgot to mention, I want the digits to stay int when I put them in the array, I don't want them converted to char

Comment: What does "stay int" mean?

Comment: @piper1935 - The basis of what you're looking for is the amswer given by David.  You mod 10 the number to get the last digit, and divide the number by 10.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I would like the digits to be type int as they are put into the array.  I realise this would be easier if I converted the integer to a character array, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: And exactly what is the problem with the solution you posted? I don't really see anything wrong...

Comment: Okay, let me provide some more context.  This function is part of a class that reads digits into an array.  The class has overloaded io operators so I can use cout << on the array contents.  However, the above code I've written is not successfully putting the integers into the array, which I have determined because I am unable to print them.  The only other thing I can think of is an issue with the cout operator

Answer (score 2):

You could take the result of the number mod ten which would give you the current digit in the ones place, then divide the number by ten to move the digits to the right one place, and do this for every digit.

This does sound suspiciously like a homework problem though, which is why my answer is vague...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const std::string test_data = "12345";
std::vector<char> digits;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < test_data.length; ++i)
{
  if (isdigit(test_data[i]))
  {
    digits.push_back(test_data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what they are looking for I believe. They are starting with an integer, rather than a string.

Comment: Isolating digits is a lot easier when the number is kept as a string rather than converting the string to an integer and then having to shift each digit.  It's faster too.

Comment: Oh I agree, I was just saying that he would first have to convert it to a string from an int.

Comment: I realise it would be easier to convert the integer to a character array, but I don't want to do that because I want each extracted digit to stay type int.

Comment: Then convert the character to an integer, before pushing to a vector of integers.  This is accomplished by subtracting '0' from the character:  `int value = test_data[i] - '0';`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the problem.  The output operators for this class were overloaded in such a way that they didn't support integers.  Once I fixed that the above code using David's method worked.