# Splitting a compact string into individual ints

Tags: c++, string, file, sstream

I am attempting to write a program that reads a file line by line, and storing the contents of each line as individual integer values. A typical line might look like this:

```
7190007400050083
```

The following snippet from my code reads a single line from the file with numbers in it:

```cpp
std::ifstream file;
file.open("my_file_with_numbers");
std::string line;
file >> line;
```

I want the string to be split up into separate values and store them as integers in a vector. I have looked across the internet, but found no solutions. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: _"I want the string to be split up into separate values"_ how do you split? _"I have looked across the internet, but found no solutions"_ is rather dubious, given that string manipulation is rather fundamental.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me with that brilliant solution, @PasserBy

Comment: `auto value{ std::stoll(line) };`  Then do whatever you want to do with `value`.

Comment: You can leave sarcastic comments and get nowhere or you can [edit] your question with necessary requirements and tell us what conceptual roadblock you're stuck on after reading about string manipulation.

Comment: @PasserBy I am sad to see my post getting downvoted so much, if I could be more clear in the future please let me know how. My reaction, though, was to your comment. Couldn't you just say "I don't understand what you are asking for, can you elaborate"?

Comment: @Eljay This does not split a string into separate values.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow • It is unclear in the question how many digits comprise a value.  From the given answer below, apparently it's one digit per value.

Comment: I pointed out where I didn't understand. You didn't specify how things are supposed to be split, and you didn't say what about string manipulations you don't understand.

Comment: [How do I split an int into its digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261589/how-do-i-split-an-int-into-its-digits) and [Reading individual digits of an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489534/reading-individual-digits-of-an-integer) and also [separate digits of a long number in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341045/separate-digits-of-a-long-number-in-c)

Comment: Side note: get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this cast that means changing `std::ifstream file; file.open("my_file_with_numbers");` to `std::ifstream file("my_file_with_numbers");`.

Comment: You keep getting downvoted because the question doesn't clearly state what the rule is for transforming that string into numbers, and you haven't edited it to make it clear.

Comment: How many digits per number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want one value per digit, you can do e.g.

```
std::vector<int> vec(line.length());
std::transform(begin(line), end(line), begin(vec),
               [](char const& ch)
               {
                   return ch - '0';
               });
```

For the input string `"7190007400050083"` you will get the vector `{ 7, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 8, 3 }`.

---

Otherwise, how large can the numbers be? Can they be negative? Why not read it directly into integers to begin with, why use a string?

For this, and again with an assumption that the values will all fit in a 64-bit unsigned integer type:

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> vec;
unsigned long long value;
while (file >> value)
{
    vec.push_back(value);
}
```

The above is the naive and beginner solution, but there are other ways:

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> vec(
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned long long>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<unsigned long long>());
```

For arbitrary length integer values, you need a "bignum" library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: @Some programmer dude And how is the last function vec defined?:)